# How can I get my appended link text on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi everyone I have created my own Jquery/javascript auto complete search suggestions div.  It basically pulls in an xml dictionary full of words and uses a reg exp to check matches against entered characters and then populates a div with those matches.  This all works perfectly fine but when it came to fancying up my div suggestion box I cannot alter the appended text links in the box at all.  When the user clicks on one of the suggested link texts I want that text to appear in the search box but the text is coming back is empty in an alert. I have tried using the delegate function and live function on click; this allows me to click one of the links but an alert shows nothing-completely blank. Any help would be great thanks.

here is my click handler

```
$("#suggestions a").live('click', function() {
  alert(this);
  $("#term_search").val(this).text();
  });
```

and the main code to populate the div

```
     $(data).find("word").each(function(){  
  $("#suggestions").show();
  var text=$(this).text();
  var re = new RegExp(word,"g","gi",".*");
  if((text).match(re)){
  $("#suggestions").append('<a>'+(text)+'</a>'+'<br/>');
```

Comment: `live` was deprecated in 1.7 and removed in 1.9. You should start using on() so when you upgrade to a modern version it does not bite you in the butt.

Comment: Thanks I will keep that in mind and use on() from now on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using

```
$("#term_search").val($(this).text());
```

also .live() is deprecated, use on() instead. here is how your code should look like

```
$("#suggestions").on('click','a', function() {
  $("#term_search").val($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much it works like this  $("#suggestions").on('click','a', function() {
  $("#term_search").val($(this).text());
});

Answer (score 0):

You need to do like this

```
$("#suggestions").live('click','a' function() {
  alert(this);
  $("#term_search").val($(this).text());
});
```

***Note:*** If you are using newer version of jQuery library (1.7+) then you should use `on` instead of `live`,it was deprecated in 1.7 and removed in 1.9.

Also you need to change `...val(this).text();` to `...val($(this).text());`

Comment: when I try this it says [object HTMLDivElement]

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like meaningful code.

```
$("#term_search").val(this).text();
```

It might need to be more like

```
$("#term_search").val( $(this).text() );
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help I understand now where I was going wrong.